# конвертация времени из разных временны́х зон

Tags: shell, временная-зона

время от времени получаю от *redhat*-а приглашения для участия в «вебинарах».

дата и время в письмах указана в таком, например, виде:

> Thursday, August 13, 2015 | 11 a.m. ET | 8 a.m. PT

как в *shell*-е узнать, во сколько состоится это событие в моей временно́й зоне?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

вначале про обозначения:

- *et* — это [*eastern time zone*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eastern_Time_Zone), [*североамериканское восточное время*](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8F), в этой зоне находится, например, нью-йорк.
- *pt* — это [*pacific time zone*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pacific_Time_Zone), [*североамериканское тихоокеанское время*](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC%E2%88%9208:00), в этой зоне находится, например, лос-анджелес.

всё бы ничего, но в этих временны́х зонах есть деление на летнее и зимнее время:

- в зоне *et* летом — это *edt*, зимой — *est*
- в зоне *pt* летом — это *pdt*, зимой — *pst*

чтобы вычислить, какое время — зимнее или летнее актуально в указанную дату (и время) в этих городах, можно выполнить такие команды:

```
$ TZ=America/New_York date -d 'Thursday, August 13, 2015 11 a.m.'
Thu Aug 13 11:00:00 EDT 2015
$ TZ=America/Los_Angeles date -d 'Thursday, August 13, 2015 8 a.m.'
Thu Aug 13 08:00:00 PDT 2015
```

видно, что в указанный момент времени там будет актуально: *edt* — в нью-йорке, и *pdt* — в лос-анджелесе.

---

теперь, собственно, можно посмотреть, сколько времени будет в указанный момент во временной зоне, которая указана в настройках вашей системы:

```
$ date -d 'Thursday, August 13, 2015 11 a.m. edt'
Thu Aug 13 18:00:00 MSK 2015
$ date -d 'Thursday, August 13, 2015 8 a.m. pdt'
Thu Aug 13 18:00:00 MSK 2015
```

---

ну а если хочется узнать, сколько в это время будет, например, во владивостоке или в берлине? нет ничего проще:

```
$ TZ=Asia/Vladivostok date -d 'Thursday, August 13, 2015 11 a.m. edt' 
Fri Aug 14 01:00:00 VLAT 2015
$ TZ=Europe/Berlin date -d 'Thursday, August 13, 2015 11 a.m. edt'
Thu Aug 13 17:00:00 CEST 2015
```

---

финальный вопрос: откуда взята вся эта информация для переменной *TZ*?

из [базы данных временны́х зон](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tz_database), которую в настоящее время поддерживает организация [iana на своём сайте](https://www.iana.org/time-zones).

информация там регулярно обновляется — вследствие, например, указов правительств государств об изменениях часовых поясов на своей территории, или каких-нибудь гео-политических «рокировок» ([типа присоединения каких-нибудь полу-островов к каким-нибудь государствам](http://politichanka.livejournal.com/195198.html?thread=20189054#t20189054)).

оттуда информацию черпают различные дистрибутивы различных операционных систем. в дистрибутивах операционной системы *gnu/linux* базу данных можно увидеть в каталоге `/usr/share/zoneinfo`.